# change value on an input with val() and trigger('change')

Tags: jquery, symfony, triggers

I have a list of button with for each a specific value, I would like to get one of these value when I click on the button then put this value into a specific input. I am using symfony and jquery to do it.
Here is my code:

The different button with specific value :

```
{% block body %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box ">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 header-title">{{ "Données traitement"|trans }}</h2>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
                {% for s in secteur %}
                    <button id="linkSecteur_{{ s.SecteurId }}" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur essai" data-id="{{ s.SecteurId }}">{{ s.LibLong }}</button>
                {% endfor  %}
            </div>
```

The input where I want to put the value selected with the button:

```
        <form id="searchForm" class="form-horizontal search-form " role="form" action="{{ path('api_post', {id: odata_search}) }}" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-8">{{ form_row(form.Secteur) }}</div>
```

Here it the test that I try to fix :

```
var $searchFieldSecteur = $("#form_Secteur");

            $('#linkSecteur_02').on('click',function() {

               var long = $(this).val('hello');
                //console.log(long);
                $searchFieldSecteur.val(long).trigger('change')
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by value you meant the button's data-id attr then using .val() wont help you, you have to use attr()

```js
var $searchFieldSecteur = $("#form_Secteur");

// use a class instead of id to make the rule apply on multiple buttons
$('.z-btn-secteur').on('click', function() {

  // get value from data-id attribute
  var long = $(this).attr('data-id');
  console.log(long);
  $searchFieldSecteur.val(long).trigger('change')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background:white">
  <button id="linkSecteur_01" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur essai" data-id="01">button 1</button>
  <button id="linkSecteur_02" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur essai" data-id="02">button 2</button>
  <button id="linkSecteur_03" class="text-lg-left btn btn-link z-btn-secteur essai" data-id="03">button 3</button>

  <form id="searchForm" style="margin-top:25px" class="form-horizontal search-form " role="form" method="post">
    <input id="form_Secteur" type="text">
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Hello Zurupupz, thank you very much for your quick and complete answer it's works perfectly.